# remove trailing spaces from text files ONLY when necessary

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, awk, sed

I'm removing the trailing spaces using

```
sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//' *.txt
```

However, this command will rewrite all the files.

Is there a convenient way to judge that if there are trailing spaces in a text file and skip those without trailing spaces?

Comment: I'd regard this as getting too complicated to process with sed, gawk, etc. and I'd write a Python script instead. This is a  comment because I'm not about to write it and Python migh be regarded as off-topic or "cheating"  or even not available in an embedded-system scenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `grep` first to find if there are lines that need modifying, though that would still read the files twice at worst (in the case where just the last line needs modifying):

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
    grep -q '[[:blank:]]$' "$f" &&
      sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' "$f"
done
```

Comment: You could add `-m1` to `grep` to stop reading the file once it finds a match.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity with `-q` I'm fairly sure `grep` stops immediately it's found a match

Comment: yes, `-q` should do that (that's what the manpage and the POSIX text say). The worst case is still that `grep` has to read the whole file before finding a match and having `sed` do it again.

Comment: @roaima of course! I just was convinced it just meant "quiet", not that it quited

Comment: @ilkkachu that's because BREs don't know what `\t` is. GNU `grep` can handle it just fine, as long as you use `-E` or `-P` to enable a regex flavor that supports them.

Comment: @terdon, `\t` isn't ERE either. But GNU grep does support other extensions like `\w`, `\s` and `\<`/`\>` regardless of `-E`. (But not e.g. `\d` in the version I tried.) The Perl regex parser might well be different, sure.

Comment: I'm actually fairly stunned to find that GNU grep doesn't match `\t` as a tab whether `-E` is used or not (but I didn't expect to need `-E`). I'd have sworn that worked - The Mandela Effect may have struck again :-).

Answer (score 7):

One way can be with `find/grep/sed` as shown:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' \
  -exec grep -q '[[:blank:]]$' {} \; \
  -exec sed -Ei -e 's/[[:blank:]]+$//' {} +
```

- the find with -maxdepth if 1 operates within the current directory.
- `{} \;`  is referring to the name of the file being passed to `grep` and `\;` is escaping the shell meta character semicolon which is an end of command indicator. We escape it so that it reaches `-exec`. You could have alternatively written it as `';'`
- `{} +`  you already know `{}` now and that `+` signifies you pass as many filenames as is possible to `sed` (basically, instead of passing the single `{}` of the current `find` result, accumulate a list of `{}` to be used as argument before calling `sed`). This allows us to minimize the number of `sed` invocations.

Answer (score 6):

Perform the edit, and only substitute the original file if there is a difference.

```
for file in *.txt
do
    sed 's/[ \t]*$//' < "$file" > "$file.tmp.$$" || continue
    cmp -s -- "$file" "$file.tmp.$$" ||
      cat < "$file.tmp.$$" > "$file" ||
      continue
    rm -f -- "$file.tmp.$$"
done
```

Comment: Why `-f` in `rm -f`? It seems safer to let it fail if the file is read protected for some reason as that should never happen unless something has gone wrong (wrong file, for example).

Comment: @terdon thanks for edit. I always use `rm -f` in a script to avoid unintended `rm: remove write-protected regular file` questions if the file is missing write permissions. (It's also part of a `sed file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file; rm -f file.tmp` construct that I often use. Here I've avoided that because I don't know about the OP's context such as hard-linked files or permissions.)

Comment: You could improve that a bit with `tmp=$(mktemp) && for file in *.txt;
do
    sed 's/[ \t]*$//' "$file" > "$tmp" && diff -q "$file" "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$file"; done; rm -f -- "$tmp"`

Comment: `rm -f` would be needed to inhibit the complaint if the temp file would be missing write permission. But for that to happen, it would need to be created without them two lines earlier. Which would happen if the user has umask set to e.g. `0222`. But... if they can have a weird umask, then what about an umask of `0777`? The file would be created with no permissions at all, the `cmp` would _fail_ and the `cat` would run and fail without being able to read the temp file, but not before trashing the original file...

Comment: That could be guarded for by checking if `cmp` exits with a status of `1` for mismatch or `2` for error. Or, and I think it's fair: using an umask like that could just be called a user error.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `xargs` (cons: the files are read twice, by `grep` and `sed`):

```bsh
$ grep -l '[[:blank:]]\+$' *.txt | xargs sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]\+$//'
```

---

- `grep -l '[[:blank:]]\+$'` get a list of the files that match the pattern.
- `xargs sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]\+$//'` perform the `sed` command over that list of files.

Answer (score 2):

The following builds on [roaima's idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675884/493832) of running the `sed` expression across all files, but then only keeping the files that were actually modified.

It modifies that by doing fewer `sed` invocations:

```bsh
printf '%s\0' ./*.txt |
xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/[[:blank:]]$//
```

You may then go through the `*.txt` files, comparing them with the originals and picking the one that you want to keep:

```bsh
for name in ./*.txt; do
    if cmp -s "$name" "$name.bak"; then
        # keep original
        mv "$name.bak" "$name"
    else
        # keep modified
        rm "$name.bak"
    fi
done
```

Or, doing both in one go:

```bsh
printf '%s\0' ./*.txt |
xargs -0 sh -c '
    sed -i.bak "s/[[:blank:]]$//" "$@"
    for name do
        if cmp -s "$name" "$name.bak"; then
            mv "$name.bak" "$name"
        else
            rm "$name.bak"
        fi
    done' sh
```

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of thing, on GNU systems, I generally do things like:

```
grep -rlZ pattern . | xargs -r0 sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Or for filenames with a given extension:

```
grep -rlZ --include='*.txt' pattern . |
  xargs -r0 sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Or for only the regular files in the current directory, with `zsh`:

```
print -rNC1 -- ./*.txt(N.) |
  xargs -r0 grep -lZ pattern |
  xargs -r0 sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Here, your pattern would be `[[:blank:]]\{1,\}$` (or `[[:blank:]]+` with `-E`) and replacement nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Just limit the domain range - or the files you operate on.

Here is what I do nowdays.. Provided you don't mind having a "modern grep" like `ack`, `ag`, `rg`:

1. Find what you are looking for
2. Convert that into an input list
3. Run sed on it

Find the files matching a pattern (trailing spaces in your case, _Slack for me).

```
$ ag _Slack  
main/Makefile
4:Benchmark_Sample1_Slack:   ; @go test -run=$@ -bench=$@ -count=1 -benchtime=1ns && echo -- && echo && cat output/$@
9:Benchmark_Sample2_Slack:   ; @go test -run=$@ -bench=$@ -count=1 -
(...)

main/samples_test.go
192:func sampleX_Slack(write func(s string), samples []monalert.CliOptions) {
(...)
```

Convert that into a list of input files

```
$ ag _Slack  -l
```

Sed it.

```
$ ag --type=go _Slack  -l | xargs sed -Ee '...' -i
```

So instead of --type=go, you could use --type=txt. I like this approach because it doesn't require a lot of intricate syntax.
Sed with -E (extended regex) is preferable because it's closer to what `ag`, `ack` and `rg` expects, so you can reuse the pattern.